# phpseclib SSH2 login works on command line, not through service

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I puzzled why the same php script works on the command line, but not when the php script is run as a service on Debian.

This is the code that doesn't work as a service-php-script:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2("localhost", $port);
if($ssh->login("loginname", "password"))
{
   // success
}
else
{
   // failed
}
```

I'm guessing it has to do with rights permissions, but I couldn't find anything about giving the systemd/service the rights to use the phpseclib SSH2 login.

Thank you for any feedback!

Comment: I kinda wonder if the deeper issue is that `fsockopen` has been disabled. eg. does `fsockopen("localhost", $port)` give you an error?  That said, something else that could be useful: do `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` at the top and `echo $ssh->getLog();` after the failed login attempt.

Comment: Hi neubert, thank you for replying! I have have tested your fsockopen() both in command line and in a running service. Both work fine.

I also tried the getLog(). What should I be looking for in the output? In the right column I see a lot email addresses and notes that I don't understand.

Comment: Add the notes to pastebin.com and then post the link here.

Comment: Hi neubert, I have discovered what I did wrong: I forgot to add "dirname(__FILE__)" to the include statement... Now it works like a charm in a service.

Thank you for your support!